# Autocomplete textbox in MVC returning '[ ]' when values populated from databse and does not show the view with the textbox control placed in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I used the following code to implement autocomplete textbox in MVC. But when I debug the project it shows a pair of angle brackets in the browser. pls examine my code.

controller:

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string searchstr)
{
 var tenders = db.farmas.Where(t => t.Itemname.ToLower()
.Contains(searchstr.ToLower())).Take(10)
.OrderBy(t => t.Itemname)
.Select(t => new { label = t.Itemname });
return Json(tenders, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

}

view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h2>Autocomplete</h2>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css rel="stylesheet"           

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js">   
</script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/javascript")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Itemname').autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
$.getJSON("/NewDefault1/Autocomplete?term=" + request.term, function    (data) {
response(data);
});
},
minLength: 3,
delay: 100
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
<div style="padding: 20px;">
 pls type in the textbox
</div>
<div style="padding: 20px;">
 Product: @Html.TextBox("Itemname")
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

before I had this error that downloaded the file with JSON extension.when the     project is debug,which contained the same square brackets as its contents and now the same is shown on the browser .  what is wrong in the code? where am I wrong? I also went through the jquery-ui website,but i am not able to make out how to populate the textbox values from database. any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using "/NewDefault1/Autocomplete?searchstr=" instead "/NewDefault1/Autocomplete?term=".

Comment: Also you can test if any data being fetched from your controller by pasting the URL:
"{url}/NewDefault1/Autocomplete?term=a" instead of a send some promising search string. Atleast you will know is it client or server side problem.

Comment: I just tried it.. not working. The issue is the Autocomplete view with the textbox is not at all been shown when i debug. It directly gives '[]' as the output in the browser.

Comment: the searchstr in the controller is catching a null value when debugged

Comment: when tried as u said @theinsaneone specifying the url, the values are fetched.. but why doesnt it work?

Comment: hi, when values are fetched, are there any values in it? or is it just []. '[]' means empty result is returned.

Comment: when I specified the searchstr in the url as {url}/NewDefault1/Autocomplete?searchstr=a", it results in displaying "[label: abc, label: ade]" so on, that is the values in my db.. but when the url is {url}/NewDefault1/Autocomplete ,it does not show the autocomplete view where I have placed the txtbox and it displays []. this is when it is run on google chrome. When IE 11.0 is used to debug, it asks for a json file named "autocomplete.json" to be downloaded. PLs help. I couldnt figure out the issue.

Comment: '{url}/NewDefault1/Autocomplete?searchstr=a' when this is returning you some values in JSON, is your auto-complete working on chrome and IE both??? Secondly, '{url}/NewDefault1/Autocomplete' this URL will never work. You can check the relation between URL and action/controllers on internet. Explaining it here, wont be appropriate.

Comment: it worked on both IE and chrome.